# Replacing a document in mongo db is not updating timestamps. Is there any alternative in schema level?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Method I used for replacing a document in mongo-db:

```
db.collection.findOneAndReplace(
   <filter>,
   <replacement>,
   {
     projection: <document>,
     sort: <document>,
     maxTimeMS: <number>,
     upsert: <boolean>,
     returnNewDocument: <boolean>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the current time into a document upon a write:

- Use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/
- Calculate the time in your application and store it explicitly as a timestamp